# Just learning javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to, build a Family Tree. I will be creating a class for grandparents that includes properties: Hair Color, Eye Color, and Vertical. Hair Color and Eye Color can be strings, but Vertical should be a method that display how high the person can jump in the console. and I have to have parent and child incorporated into the code how do I do so?

```
'use strict'
class user{
  constructor(hairColor, eyeColor, vertical){
        this.hairColor = hairColor;
        this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
        this.vertical = vertical;
    }

    register(){
        console.log(+'Grandma can jump'+this.vertical+'inches'+);
    }

}
let grandma = new user ('white', 'blue', 10);
grandma.register();
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking new questions

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, first take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Else your code has error in the register method().

```
console.log('Grandma can jump'+this.vertical+'inches'); //remove first and last +
```

Comment: That last `+` is probably not necessary either.

Comment: yes missed it! thanks!